# Getting 'cannot find module' error in nextJS development build

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

getting errror when i start the localHost for UI No able to resolve this error

use this commad for install the **npx create-next-app@latest**

Package.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "next": "13.4.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

getting error in Browser:-

```
caught Error: Could not find the module "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\test\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\app-router.js#" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler.
```